# Pandas read_csv randomly skip rows with specific entries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file where I want to skip a random percentage of rows but only for rows where one of the columns has a specific entry. For example I might have a csv with contents below and I want to skip a certain percentage of all the apple entries:

```
 | a  | b  | c  | d  | e      |
 |----|----|----|----|--------|
0| 9  | 1  | 2  | 3  | apple  |
1| 8  | 4  | 5  | 6  | apple  |
2| 7  | 7  | 8  | 9  | apple  |
3| 6  | 10 | 11 | 12 | orange |
4| 5  | 13 | 14 | 15 | orange |
5| 4  | 16 | 17 | 18 | orange |
6| 3  | 19 | 20 | 21 | orange |
7| 2  | 22 | 23 | 24 | banana |
8| 1  | 25 | 26 | 27 | banana |
9| 0  | 28 | 29 | 30 | banana |
```

I know I could skip rows across the entire file with something like

```
 df = pd.read_csv('fruit.csv', skiprows = lambda i: i>0 and random.random() > probability_value)
```

I know I can also select just the apple entries from the dataframe with

```
df2 = df.loc[df['e'] == 'apple']
```

But is there a simple way to select these entries when importing the csv and apply the skip rows so all the non 'apple' entries aren't affected by the skip row?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows, But I would prefer doing it in later stage.

```
df = pd.read_csv('fruit.csv').query("e != 'apple'")
```